# reset cygwin environment like it first run

Tags: initialization, cygwin, reset

to be clear, I am not talking about how to reset terminal characters of cygwin.

what I would like to achieve is, **how to re-run cygwin as "First run"**.

background: I accidentally delete all my home directory files, so all profiles are gone.
I would like cygwin re-generate/re-initialize it again for me like its "First run / Fresh start"

thanks

Comment: if the directory of your home (`/home/your-user-name`) is missing the startup script will recreate it and copied the default files again.

Comment: so what you suggest is to delete it?

Comment: ha! that's trick is working! thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks @matzeri for the trick. that's definitely works!

so, to re-initialize my cygwin like first-run, what I do is:

```
username@computername ~
$ pwd
/home/username

username@computername ~
$ cd /home

username@computername ~
$ mv username username-old

username@computername ~
$ exit
```

exit all cygwin terminal, and run the cygwin again from start menu. your will see following output means your profiles is re-created again.

```
These files are for the users to personalise their cygwin experience.

They will never be overwritten nor automatically updated.

'./.bashrc' -> '/home/username//.bashrc'
'./.bash_profile' -> '/home/username//.bash_profile'
'./.inputrc' -> '/home/username//.inputrc'
'./.profile' -> '/home/username//.profile'
```

restore my working data:

```
username@computername ~
$ cd /home

username@computername ~
$ ls 
username   username-old

username@computername ~
$ mv username-old/mydata username/
```